# Converting WMS data to Raster using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, wms, getmap

I have this WMS link (https://www.lfu.bayern.de/gdi/wms/wasser/wassertiefen? ) which contains data about different flooding depths.

I'd like to convert this layer [wt_hqextrem] or "Wassertiefen für HQextrem" to a Raster.

So far I've tried to "Extract by Mask" in ArcGIS but was not able to select the layer.

I then tried to do a `GetMap` Request but either obtain a blank image or an error file/page.

Here is what I tried : https://www.lfu.bayern.de/gdi/wms/wasser/wassertiefen?VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&LAYERS=wt_hqextrem&STYLES=&SRS=EPSG:4326&BBOX=8.205988,46.781936,14.641022,51.030572&WIDTH=1200&HEIGHT=1200&FORMAT=image/png&transparent=true&

Here is the Capabilities page from the data provider (in German): https://geoportal.bayern.de/getcapabilities/CapabilitiesViewer?ows_url=https://www.lfu.bayern.de/gdi/wms/wasser/wassertiefen?&format=html&link=true

How can I convert this data to a Raster?

Comment: A WMS is a picture, you need to find a WCS instead to download a raster

Comment: You can't create data from a rendered map image, I suggest seeing if the data is available for download (https://www.lfu.bayern.de/umweltdaten/geodatendienste/index.htm)

Comment: Note the service layers are scale dependent, if you request an image outside of the scale range you will get a blank image.

Comment: `https://www.lfu.bayern.de/gdi/wms/wasser/wassertiefen?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.3.0&REQUEST=GetMap&BBOX=49.05002877074240786,10.54469963650825015,49.2221897635860941,10.86194465853241375&CRS=EPSG:4326&WIDTH=1570&HEIGHT=852&LAYERS=wt_hqextrem&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=TRUE` gives a map